# Password Module for Expression Engine?

Tags: authentication, passwords, expressionengine

Just wondering if someone could help me approach a clients request.

Is there any modules for expression engine for password protected pages?

I need to set up a form for the user to fill out and choose a password and username, this would then give them access to a separate section/page on the site?

How could I approach this with EE?

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to password-protect pages in an ExpressionEngine site:

- Template Preferences Manager
- Conditional Global Variables
- Third-Party Add-Ons

By far the easiest solution is to use the built-in [Template Preferences Manager](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/design/templates/template_preferences_manager.html) in the ExpressionEngine Control Panel.

1). Using the **Template Access Restrictions** feature, you can restrict an entire page/template to one or more defined groups (Banned, Guests, Members, Pending and Custom Groups).

When a restricted page is accessed, you can configure what should happen:

- Show a Specific Template (e.g. a Login or Error Page)
- Enable HTTP Authentication

2). If you need to conditionally show *part of a page* to a specific member or group, you can use [Conditional Global Variables](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/globals/conditionals.html).

**Conditional Variables** are pair type variables, which allow you to conditionally show or hide information on your pages based on criteria being met. For example, a basic conditional variable will look like this:

```
{if username == "joe"}
    Hi Joe!
{/if}
```

More advanced conditionals can use logical operators (ex: OR, AND) to compare multiple variables to multiple values. Consider this example:

```
{if username == "joe" OR username == "bob"}
    Hey, Guys!
{/if}
```

There are many Global Conditionals you can use. See the [Global Variables](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/globals/index.html) section of the ExpressionEngine User Guide for more information.

3). Finally, if you need more advanced or granular control for password-protecting content in ExpressionEngine, a **Third-Party Add-On** may give you what you need.

One such popular add-on is the [Solspace User Module](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/user/). It gives you a robust set of front-end member management tools and adds flexibility to the way your member management behaves.

Using other third-party add-ons, you can password protect files, certain channel entries for certain members or member groups and more! All of this is possible due to the [ExpressionEngine Developer API](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/development/index.html).

You can leverage any number of the third-party Developer Add-Ons at [Devot-ee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ee2/) -- the official community partner devoted to ExpressionEngine Add-Ons.

Answer (score 3):

Any content in EE can be wrapped in a conditional statement using the `logged_in_group_id` global variable, so a module isn't really needed.

So you can have your users fill out a member registration form (I'd recommend the [Solspace User module](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/user/) for this), setup to register them into your chosen member group.

Then, wrap your members-only content like this (use the appropriate ID for your member group):

```
{if logged_in_group_id == 6}
    Members-only content here.
{/if}
```

Alternately, you could use something like this: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-access/