# How do I use htaccess to limit access to entries?

Tags: .htaccess, expressionengine

I need to password protect a couple of entries on a site. It is easy to do at the template level but this is at the entry level. I am running Expression Engine.

I tried setting up an htaccess file but it is not yet effective.

It is like this:

```
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /home/server/.htpasswds/.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
<Files template_group/entry_name>
require valid-user
</Files>
```

Where template_group is the name of the actual template_group and entry_name is the actual name of the entry.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While ExpressionEngine provides its own means for [Template Access Restriction](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/design/templates/template_access.html) to password-protect pages and templates — *including handling .htaccess Apache Basic HTTP Authentication* — there are situations where you might not want to, or are unable, to use it:

- For example, the [Freelancer Version](http://expressionengine.com/overview/pricing) of ExpressionEngine doesn't include the [Member Management Module](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/member/overview.html), so the [Template Preferences Manager](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/design/templates/template_preferences_manager.html) doesn't offer Access Restrictions.
- Also, if you elect to use ExpressionEngine's HTTP Authentication, only users with member accounts [in ExpressionEngine] will be able to login, since EE uses its local member database for authentication.

**If you're the DIY type, you can modify your `httpd.conf` to limit and password-protect access to ExpressionEngine pages, entries and templates**.

This technique works by:

1. Editing Apache's `httpd.conf`
2. Creating `.htpasswd` or `.htgroup` files
3. Specifying the URL(s) to Protect

*Note: Since we are attempting to match objects at the URL level and not the physical filesystem, we must use a `<Location>` or `<LocationMatch>` directive<sup>1</sup>.*

Put the following in your server's `httpd.conf` or `vhost.conf` file:

```
<LocationMatch "^/private">
    AuthName "Restricted Area"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /path/to/website/.htpasswd
    AuthGroupFile /dev/null
    Require valid-user
</LocationMatch>
```

Be sure to change the values of the directive to your liking and your hosting environment.

If you haven't already, create the `.htpasswd` password file to encrypt the desired passwords, either using the command line or an [Online .htaccess Password Generator](http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/password/):

`htpasswd -c /path/to/website/.htpasswd username`

If the htpasswd command is not in your Unix path, you'll have to type the full path to the file to get it to run. On my server, it would be:

`/usr/sbin/htpasswd -c /path/to/website/.htpasswd username`

Then, htpasswd will ask you for the user's password, and ask you to type it again to confirm:

```
# htpasswd -c /path/to/website/.htpasswd username
New password: changeme
Re-type new password: changeme
Adding password for user username
```

**With everything in place and working, any request to `/private*` will be handled by Apache before it's routed to ExpressionEngine.**

---

Voilà — Apache password-protected directories working in harmony with ExpressionEngine (or any CMS really, such as WordPress, MovableType or TextPattern).

> 1. *The [context](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/directive-dict.html#Context) of the `<Location>` directive specifies that it can only be used in `server config` and `virtual host` configuration files. This means we can't put the rules in a `.htaccess` file, otherwise Apache will throw a **500 Internal Server Error** with the description "Location not allowed here".*
>
>    - If you are attempting to match objects at the URL level, you must use `<Location>`
>    - If you are attempting to match objects at the filesystem level, you must use `<Directory>` and/or `<Files>`

Answer (score 1):

I answered two [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097662/password-module-for-expression-engine/6112141#6112141) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097130/trying-to-password-protect-a-url-with-htaccess/6118102#6118102) on this subject that may be of benefit to you.

Nevertheless, there are several ways to password-protect pages in an ExpressionEngine site:

- Template Preferences Manager
- Conditional Global Variables
- Third-Party Add-Ons

By far the easiest solution to your situation is to use the built-in [Template Preferences Manager](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/design/templates/template_preferences_manager.html) in the ExpressionEngine Control Panel and assign the "private" entries to a template that requires authentication.

A third-party add-on such as [Entry Access](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-access/) by Yuri Salimovskiy of IntoEEtive may aide in your benefit. ***Entry Access*** enables you to restrict front-end access to certain channel entries for certain members or member group.

Comment: Hi rjb, that was my first thought as well. However, the template is used by other entries that need to be freely accessed. From you comment though it looks like I may need to create a private template. Is htaccess a viable option?

Comment: That was really the best and easiest option. Thanks.